# Shorten the comma separated CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Maybe the title of this question is ambiguous, what I really mean is:

```css
#footer_list li a:link, #footer_list li a:visited
{
    blah balh blah
}
```

Is there a shortcut for the two elements in CSS? so the CSS selectors can be shortened

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. If you give them each their own respective class/id names. But thats unnecessary. The code you have is perfectly acceptable, as CSS *is* Cascading Style Sheets, the rules cascade down essentially.

Comment: whenever I type/paste something "redundant" I always think I must do it in a wrong way :(

Comment: Not only are classes unnecessary, but they don't work as they can't substitute pseudo-classes. (I'm just giving a friendly expansion on your answer here though.)

Comment: @Michael Mao: Questioning things is a good trait to have. But, don't automatically assume its the wrong way. If it works, then use it. *this should be taken with a grain of salt*

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine as is. I've been styling my sites with selectors like that and it hasn't bothered me or the browsers.

If your server runs Ruby and you don't mind picking up a server-side "extension" to the standard CSS syntax, [LESS](http://lesscss.org) provides nested rules so you can do something like this:

```
#footer_list li {
    a:link {
        /* Styles for normal links */
    }
    a:visited {
        /* Styles for visited links */
    }
}
```

---

OK, I'm not sure what differences this will make, but I'm sure it'll be treated differently by browsers:

```
#footer_list li a {
    /* Styles */
}
```

You can then place additional `a` selectors with classes or `a:hover` or `a:active` below that and they'll work when applicable.

Comment: WOW! that's something I didn't know... I will check this out with my hosting server and see if I can do this there :)

Comment: @Michael Mao: I updated my answer again. See if the last (LESS not needed) selector works for you.

Comment: Oh delicious nested CSS selectors. I can't figure out why CSS isn't nested when it's designed to style (X)HTML, the most insanely nested thing ever conceived of.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have links within `#footer_list` that aren't within `li` elements?  Do you have any other lists within your footer?

I'm imagining you have something like this in your markup:

```
<div id="footer">
    <p>&copy; me 2010</p>
    <ul id="footer_list">
        <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li>....
    </ul>
    <p>Some other text...</p>
</div>
```

In this case your rule only needs:

```
#footer a:link, #footer a:visited
```

If you do (or might later) have links outside the `ul` which you want to style differently you could do:

```
#footer_list a:link, #footer_list a:visited
```