# How to set one CSS rule for two tags?

Tags: html, css, tags

I would like to know how I can set one setting for two different classes.

To give an example:

```css
.footer #one .flag li .drop_down form div{
    width: 80px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight:bolder;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.footer #two .flag li .drop_down form div{
    width: 80px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight:bolder;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Both rules have the same content. The difference is just the second tag. Is there a way to do something like this?

```css
.footer >>>#one and #two<<<< .flag li .drop_down form div{
        width: 80px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.5;
        color: #ccc;
        font-weight:bolder;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
```

Comment: You should [use efficient CSS selectors](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#UseEfficientCSSSelectors) if possible.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Separate the selectors with a comma:

```css
.footer #one .flag li .drop_down form div,
.footer #two .flag li .drop_down form div {
    /* Rules */
}
```

From the [selectors level 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping):

> A comma-separated list of selectors represents the union of all elements selected by each of the individual selectors in the list. (A comma is U+002C.) For example, in CSS when several selectors share the same declarations, they may be grouped into a comma-separated list. White space may appear before and/or after the comma.

Answer (score 8):

In CSS you use a `,` (comma), unfortunately this is on the entire selector rather than just a section of it.

If you really wanted to make it cleaner you could give each of the `form div's` a unique id and then just `#form1, #form2`.

You can find further info in "[Shorten the comma separated CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641056/shorten-the-comma-separated-css-selectors)".

For example:

```
.footer #one .flag li .drop_down form div,
.footer #two .flag li .drop_down form div {
    width: 80px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight:bolder;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.footer #one .flag li .drop_down form div, 
.footer #two .flag li .drop_down form div{
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Separate with a comma:

```css
.footer #one .flag li .drop_down form div,
.footer #two .flag li .drop_down form div
{
   shared css
}
    
.footer #one .flag li .drop_down form div
{
   css for element one only
}
    
.footer #two .flag li .drop_down form div
{
  css for element two only
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma instead of separate CSS rules:

```
.footer #one .flag li .drop_down form div,  
.footer #two .flag li .drop_down form div {  
    width: 80px;  
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    font-size: 11px;  
    text-align: left;  
    line-height: 1.5;  
    color: #ccc;  
    font-weight:bolder;  
    margin-left: 30px;  
}
```